# How to return from webview to rootview in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, webview, barcode-scanner

I am new to iOS and Objective C programming world. I am trying to create a App which will scan the barcode then use that data to go to a website.

Now, the only issue is when I load the website using a webview, I don't know how to return to mainview/rootview. As, I have made this a view based App, I don't know how to implement navigation controller or simply a back button would do.

I have used this SDK: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/

The code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
        break;
    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
    resultText.text = symbol.data;

    CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
    UIWebView *webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *urlAddress= @"http://www.flipkart.com/search/a/books?query=";
    urlAddress =[urlAddress stringByAppendingString:resultText.text];
    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
//    [webView release];

/*    


    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; 
}
```

How can I add a back button in the webview so that I can return to main view?

Comment: why can't you add back button on navigation bar? or it is specific to requirement?

Comment: If you are using navigationcontroller you have to call: 

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: How to implement navigation bar, in the webview

Comment: if you're using navigationController you can set property in interface builder or you can show it in code: [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

Comment: How will I implement Navigation bar in webview, please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have tutorial how to implement toolbar with UIWebView:

http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/21/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-1/

Comment: Milo widziec ze jestes aktywny brahu :) Good job +1 all around :)

Comment: Dzięki, a tak jakoś ostatnio pomagałem ludziom z nudów i zaczalem prowadzic bloga o ios, bo bardzo malo materialow jest po polsku ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement the navigationBar.
You have create a `UIViewController` that contains your `UIWebView`, then you have to put this controller into your current UINavigationCotroller's stack by calling `[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourVC animated:YES];`, then as @mientus said, call `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to back to the root view controller.
So in this case i suggest you to start a new Master-Detail Application project.

If you don't want to do this, in your case just set a tag to your webView and add a UIButton with an action like this:

```
-(IBAction)removeWebView:(id)sender{
  [[self.view viewWithTag:yourWebViewTAG] removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: In the above code written by me, how will I add a tag to the webview I created inside the ViewController and again how to programmatically add a back button in webView, then use your removeWebView method.

Please say what are the edits I need to do, complete code of ViewController.m  http://cl.ly/FJ0R